# Write XML file to Amazon from another domain

Tags: php, xml, amazon-ec2

We're using a Amazon EC2 Account to handle an executable for our website.  This executable runs based on XML files on the server.   We're currently rebuilding the application and it will be easier if we write the XML from an application on another domain.

I have the code writing the XML file locally without issue, but when I try to write it directly to the Amazon EC2 directory I get a 403 Error (

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

```
$xmlFilename = "";
        $fileIndex = 1;
        do
        {
            $xmlFilename = "http://ipaddress/NewServerTesting/server";
    //      $xmlFilename = "server";
            $xmlFilename .= $fileIndex;
            $xmlFilename .= ".xml";
            $fileIndex++;
        }
        while( file_exists( $xmlFilename ) );
        $result = $domtree->save( $xmlFilename );

        if( FALSE == $result )
        {
            echo 'Failed to save the XML<br />';
            echo $xmlFilename;
        }
    }
```

I'm sure it is something simply that I need to set on the Amazon server to grant cross domain access, but I'm clueless as to where it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to write it directly the way you are currently doing it. Your trying to access the file over http as if it were on a file server, which won't work. You would have to do it at the least over FTP.

Is this the ec2 windows server used by the multiplayer software? If that's the case, you'll need to install an ftp server on it and enable access to the directory for where the xml is stored. Then use a PHP ftp client to write to that server.

Comment: That is indeed what I did and it worked perfectly.   I simply create the xml file on the local server and then ftp it to Amazon.